# How to query postgres on optional params?

Tags: postgresql

I am setting up an `REST` service and I am using `postgres` as the data store.  I want to know how to set up a `postgres` query to use optional parameters. ie:

```
SELECT * from users 
where hair_color = $1 
and eye_color = $2
```

Where $1 and $2 come from the request: [req.body.hair_color, req.body.eye_color]

What if the user didn't pass in `eye_color` and in that case I wanted all eye colors.  I assume that I don't have to make a bunch of `if/else` statements here.  What is the concise way of creating this query?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here I've made both `hair_color` and `eye_color` optional. (Pass your language's equivalent of NULL).

```
SELECT * from users where 
  ($1 is null or hair_color = $1) and 
  ($2 is null or eye_color = $2);
```

Comment: Yup, and in PostgreSQL this will tend to actually optimize out nicely - Pg will notice that `NULL IS NULL` is always true, so it doesn't need to evaluate `hair_color = NULL`. So it'll remove the whole clause. You need to be on a fairly new version of PostgreSQL (9.1, I think) for this to work when using prepared statements, though.

Comment: I'm sure it's what you meant, but to be clear, the query will still work with prepared statements, but the optimisation won't apply.

Comment: Absolutely. The where clause omission may work when you're using *parameterized statements* in the client driver even on old versions too. It's only if they're turned into server-side prepared statements that older Pg versions can't optimize it.

Comment: @CraigRinger a new optimization of prepared statements works strange sometimes - and should not to work nicely when PP is used more than 5x. So for this queries a dynamic queries is optimal still.

Comment: How do you make optional parameter with `IN` work? If parameter is NULL or Empty Array, it will throw syntax error. So it looks PostgreSQL will still validate whole query, even if I have let say `$1 is null or hair_color IN $1`

Comment: Made it work using `ANY` and array. As it also allows empty array to pass (where IN does not).

Comment: @Andrius Can you please share an example?

Comment: @TeresaPeters sure. This is using psycopg2: `AND (%(has_ids)s is false OR some_id = ANY(%(ids)s))`. I also used separate param to specify if `ids` param is empty or not. But might be able to check without as well. So if `ids` is not empty array, it will search using it, otherwise, it will pass with first option, ignoring second part.