# Optional Filters on .NET Core Query to Postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core

I am building an API with the latest `.NET Core` (in `C#`) and latest `PostgreSQL`.

A typical query returns data from several joined tables. For example, a `job` query will return data including salary, address, position title, etc.

I need a way to include `WHERE` clauses on this query, based on one or many filters, which may or may not be present (for example, filter by job posting date, but only if the user chose to).

One way to do this is to have a bunch of if statements and manually modify queries (e.g. concat a `WHERE salary > 100000` if the salary requirement was passed in. This seems very dirty.

From an answer here, Postgres seems to have null coalescing ([How to query postgres on optional params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062148/how-to-query-postgres-on-optional-params)), e.g.

```
SELECT * from jobswhere 
  ($1 is null or salary = $1) and 
  ($2 is null or jobPostDate= $2);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this with Dapper or Linq To SQL? What's the preferred way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if a ... requirement was passed in"? What does that look like?

Comment: I mean that requests come to the API from the front end. Sometimes users will require that the data is filtered by salary, job post date, job title, or some other such requirement. If such a "requirement was passed in", then I need to include a `WHERE` clause on the query to the database. Or a `WHERE AND`, if multiple.

Comment: How exactly are they passed to the API though? Query params, and you have a model that includes nullable properties for each possible filter value?

Comment: @MattU Correct.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [SqlKata](http://SqlKata.com) for writing your queries. It includes a method `When()` that must first pass a condition before including a Where clause in the generated SQL.

It uses Dapper under the hood.

If using linq, you can do

```
IQueryable query = dbContext.Blogs;
if (isSo)
{
    query = query.Where(...);
}
query.ToArray();
```

Comment: I am using LINQ, taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options I can think of. The first is to use a "predicate builder". The class may look like this (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51721533/12431728)):

**PredicateBuilder class**

```c#
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Then to implement it:

```c#
var things = context.Set<Thing>().AsQueryable();
var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<Thing>();

// For each search filter
if (filter1 != null)
{
    filter = filter.And(t => t.SomeProperty == filter1);
}

things = things.Where(filter);
```

This, of course, still requires an `if` statement for each filter. And you're asking how to get away from that. I find it a bit cleaner sometimes though.

---

**Postgres Function**

The other possibility is to create a function in Postgres that performs the query and takes the filter params, and the function performs the conditional filtering instead of it being done in the C# code.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION thing_search (
    IN p_filter_1 VARCHAR(50),
    -- other filter params
) RETURNS TABLE (
    id INT,
    -- other columns you'll return
)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT
            id,
            -- other columns
        FROM things
        WHERE
            (p_filter_1 IS NULL OR column_1 = p_filter_1)
            AND -- other filters
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then to utilize it, you use EF Core's `DbSet<T>.FromSqlInterpolated`:

```c#
var things = context.Set<Thing>()
    .FromSqlInterpolated(
        $"select * from thing_search ( {filter1}, {other_filter_params} )"
    );
```

That at least removes the need for the filtering inside the code, but of course it means your code has to invoke Postgres functions directly rather than utilizing `DbSet`s. That doesn't mean it's a bad approach. If it makes more sense and increases readability / maintainability, feel free to take this route.

Comment: Looking at this, thanks Matt. Will come back to accept an answer.